# Getting same data after clicking on uitableview cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview

I have and array of strings which is displayed in uitableview. When user taps on sort button the array is sorted and then i use [tableview reloaddata]. so that new sorted contents are displayed in table. but when i select particular cell the cell shows two texts overlapped on each other,the new sorted text and the text previously present in that cell.why is it happening so.

This is my code to display cells.

```
-  (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

static NSString *CellIdentifier  =  @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell  =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell ==   nil) {

    cell  =  [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;


} 


UILabel * timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(190, 0, 120, tableView.rowHeight)];
timeLabel.text = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] time];
[cell.contentView addSubview:timeLabel];


return cell ;
}
```

This is my code for sorting.

```
-(void)sortByTime{

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"time"
                                             ascending:NO] ;
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;

dataArray =  [sql getTableData];  // get data from sql file

sortedArray = [dataArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:sortedArray];

[dataTableView reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a problem in your code. You are using reusable cells, and the problem is that you are not re using the views inside your cell. Particulary, timeLabel. You are creating a new timeLabel every time you use a cell, and when you reuse one, you add an adicional label to your cell, that is the possible reason for the ovelapped text.

For reuse the label, you should set a TAG number for the UILabel, and before create a new uilabel, check if the cell already have one.

I would replace the code:

```
UILabel * timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(190, 0, 120, tableView.rowHeight)];
timeLabel.text = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] time];
[cell.contentView addSubview:timeLabel];
```

with:

```
UILabel * timeLabel = [cell viewWithTag:55]
if(!timeLabel) {
    timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(190, 0, 120, tableView.rowHeight)];
    timeLabel.tag = 55;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:timeLabel];
}

timeLabel.text = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] time];
```

The value for the tag number is up to you, i just use 55 as an example. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

as you want a customized cell and you just put new subviews in cell every time this is happend you have to use customized cell created in deferent nib and use it to display your data

just make new nib and load it from new nib so you got proper data

or can check is there any subview in cell's contentView then remove them first and then add new created subview